# I have error The header content contains invalid characters when sending HTTP request

Tags: node.js, request, http-headers, axios

I have function getBody, which gets body from url, on some url (I don't know exactly of which one) I always get error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:494
    throw new TypeError('The header content contains invalid characters');
```

Those urls contains mostly danish accents characters, this is maybe problem. I have set header : 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8', which set charset to UTF-8. Probably header host is problem.

I have tried using punycode, or url, which converts url to ASCII, but those converted URLs did not work.

```
function getBody(n) {
    var url = n; //urls[n];
    url = (url.indexOf('http://')==-1 && url.indexOf('https://')==-1) ? 'http://'+url : url;
    instance.get(url,
        {
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'

            },
        }
}
```